# When Google will release ActionBarCompat?

Tags: android-actionbar-compat

On the Google I/O 2013, Google has announced ActionBarCompat library.
Known whether the release date? Or may be it already released?

Comment: You should check https://code.google.com/p/iosched/ regularly, they said that the IO 2013 app uses the new ActionBarCompat. I guess they will probably release both at the same time.

Comment: Looks like it's using ActionBarSherlock

Comment: It isn't. It's that version of ActionBarCompat is filling the gaps that ActionBarSherlock was covering. Official line is to not re-write apps that are currently using ActionBarSherlock, but if you're starting a new app - use ActionBarCompat (when they release it!)

Comment: What a bunch of BS (not you, the Googlers).  To not provide a SupportLib for ActionBar, then to finally release an app, and still not fully implement ActionBarCompat, and still not release ActionBarCompat.  </sandbox>  Sorry to vent, but this is really messed up - and for what is arguably the cornerstone of the UI, and the fundamental navigation control.  I saw a post by one of the DevRels calling out their use of ActionBarCompat in the IOSchedule app (to not even do it fully is terrible).

Comment: ActionBarCompat is still not released. All the links to it, for example in: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html in Remaining backward-compatible side note - are blind, leading nowhere.  Also, the 2013 iosched app sources are not released yet. And the presentations on Google I/O mentioned them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Released in latest support library v7: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBar.html

Answer (score 1):

It was finally released on July 24th, 2013. [Here's a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc) of the announcement and code snippets for adding it to your own projects.